# Как спарсить title c сайтов используя python

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Я новичок в python и ни как не могу понять как реализовать следующую задачу.
Есть `txt` файл с доменами (около 10 000 доменов). Домены сохранены в верхнем регистре. Нужно:

- адреса доменов перенести в нижний регистр
- добавить вначале домена строку `http://`, чтобы домен потом вставить в `requests`
- сделать цикл, чтобы парсер собрал `title` с каждого домена (сайта)
- записать все в файл таблицу с двумя полями `| url сайта | title сайта |`

Comment: Здесь целых пять разных вопросов. На четыре вопроса способен ответить любой учебник по Python, вы его читали? Конкретизируйте вопрос и опишите, что на каком этапе не получается.

Answer (score 0):

Ну если я правильно понял суть вашего задания то вот.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

f = open(r'file.txt','r+')
a=[]
for i in f:
    a.append(i.lower().replace('\n',''))
    a[-1]='https://'+a[-1]
f.close()
title_list=[]
for url in a:
    r=requests.get(url)
    page=bs(r.content,'html.parser')
    title=page.find('title')
    title_list.append(url)
    title_list.append(title.text.replace('\n',''))

print(title_list)
```

Comment: Да это то самое )) только выводит ошибки. Я думаю надо прописать обработку ошибок когда нет title на сайте, то в title=page.find('title') выводить "title не найден" и еще думаю как url и title print(title_list) записать в файл xls или csv в два столбца с именами URL и TITLE а так да, большое спасибо за данное решение и потраченное на меня вермя!

Comment: вот сайт в файле 0rlova.ru по нему ошибка dns